# Disjunction in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, boolean

Is it possible to use ActiveRecord `named_scope`s to create one query with sql `OR` clauses?

When I use

```
Model.scope1.scope2
```

generated query is conjunction of these scopes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reply as this was the first google result for "active record disjunction".

With Rails 5+ you can do something like:

```rb
Model.scope1.or(Model.scope2)
```

For Rails 4.2.3+ there is a backport [here](https://gist.github.com/bf4/84cff9cc6ac8489d769e).

[Eric-Guo](https://github.com/Eric-Guo) created a gem [where-or](https://github.com/Eric-Guo/where-or) adding `or` functionality to `rails >= 
 4.2.3` also using his gem.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really what named scopes were designed to do, but you could probably use them with some additional code to get what you needed.

```
def combine_scopes(model)
  (model.scope1 + model.scope2).uniq
end
```

or allow any scopes to be combined

```
def combine_scopes(model, scope1, scope2)
  (model.send(scope1) + model.send(scope2)).uniq
end
```

you could even change that to allow any number of scopes using *args

Comment: Your method will generate multiple SQL queries. It's easy that way ;)

Comment: Personally I wouldn't do it this way, I was just suggesting a method that used named scopes. If it was me, I would just have a single named scope that used OR in the conditions parameter. Not as flexible if you have multiple named scopes, but if performance is a consideration, you might not want the additional query.