# can we OR the scopes in scope builder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, named-scope

I am using [ryanb-scope-builder](https://github.com/ryanb/scope-builder) and I am facing following issue.

```
def self.search(options)
  scope_builder do |builder|
    builder.released.visible
    builder.cheap if options[:cheap]
  end
end
```

This generates query which has :

```
builder.released.visible *AND* builder.cheap if options[:cheap]
```

Whereas I want scope to be OR'ed like

```
builder.released.visible *OR* builder.cheap if options[:cheap]
```

Is there any scope builder gem which can solve this problem ??
thanks

Comment: This question is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005488/disjunction-in-activerecord

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know this scope builder but generally, OR queries are made with Arel.

Have a look here: [ActiveRecord OR query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639656/activerecord-or-query)

Besides, I doubt this gem is that useful:

- scopes are natively easy to chain
- the last commit was in 2009

Comment: is it specific to rails 3 ? or 2.x can also use it ?

Comment: got it.. can be used version independent.